# Links com LI dentro

Tags: html

Possuo essa estrutura:

```
<ul>
<li><a></a></li>
<li><a></a></li>
</ul>
```

Ok, o que acontece, é que as vezes preciso colocar o link `<a>` acima da `li` e não dentro, como está na estrutura.
Como vocês fazem? Eu já utilizei `window.location`, mas queria saber se tem alguma forma de fazer sem usar **javascript**.

Comment: Explique melhor "colocar o clique acima da li e não dentro".

Comment: Editei, não havia percebido o erro.

Comment: A estrutura correta é o link dentro da li... Em que situação seria preciso colocar a li dentro do link?

Comment: @FelipeStoker você quer que o link fique encima do <li>?? Tipo assim? http://jsfiddle.net/k30jqdrd/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não é recomendado, e literalmente não é correto você colocar algo como:

```
<a><li></li></a>
```

Assim, como definido nas regras de padrões do HTML, pelo [w3c](http://www.w3c.br/Home/WebHome), dentro da tag `<ol>` ou `<ul>`, podemos conter somente tag `<li>`.

O que suspeito que você queira fazer, é que o bloco do `<li>` inteiro seja 'clicável', então recomendo fazer é adicionar a propriedade ***"display: block"*** no css da tag `<a>`.

Comment: Com `display:block` ele pegará todo o conteúdo dentro do `a` que respectivamente está dentro do `li`?

Comment: @FelipeStoker sim. Além de ser o modo correto de você escrever as tag, pois se fizer o <a> envolta do <li>, nada garante que ele vai funcionar em todos os browsers.